# React UseState does not update UI after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase `onSnapshot` in order to update my current user.

I'm holding the state using `UseState` and listening to Firebase changes in `UseEffect`.

It works fine when I first run the app, but when I refresh the page (ctrl + R) it stops working.

Currently I am trying to send this data using `Context Provider` and access it directly using `Context Consumer`, but of course after I'll fix this bug I'll replace it with real components.

This is my `App.js` code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    firebaseHandler.listenToUserUpdates((currentUser) => {
      setLoggedUser(currentUser);
      console.log('Updated');
    });
  }, []);

  if (loggedUser == null) {
    return <Login />;
  }

  return (
    <CurrentUserContext.Provider value={{loggedUser, setLoggedUser}}>
      <CurrentUserContext.Consumer>
        {value => <h1>{value.loggedUser.production.name}</h1>}
      </CurrentUserContext.Consumer>
    </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

And this is the code for `firebaseHandler.listenToUserUpdates`:

```
listenToUserUpdates(onChange) {
    this.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user == null) {
            onChange(null);
            return;
        }

        this.fetchCurrentUserAndProduction(user.uid, (currentUser) => { //Production is another doc on Firebase Firestore which I fetch and attach to the user's object
            onChange(currentUser);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: When you say "stops working" what do you mean? What can you see?

Is there any chance you can set up a demo repo for us to take a look at?

Comment: @LukeStorry The UI does not change. Even though the "Updated" console.log does gets called. So `setLoggedUser` does not update the UI for some reason

Comment: If you run this code in a debugger, and step through each and every line, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do in the reload?

Comment: Try extending the `console.log` to also output the value of the `currentUser` variable.